# Swift setText UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, settext

```
let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(responseString)
        self.lbl1.text = String(responseString)
```

Print Out:

```
Optional(2000 TL)
```

### [image]

My problem

```
> "self.lbl1.text = String(responseString)" Optional(  write.
```

I want to write "2000 TL"

Comment: Look at my answer just append an '!' In order to get rid of the Optional...

Comment: Don't use `NSString`. Just use `String`, e.g. `if let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { self.lbl1.text = responseString }`. Also, if doing this from background thread (e.g. `NSURLSession` completion handler), don't forget to dispatch UI updates back to the main queue.

Answer (score 4):

The immutable `responseString` is an optional, so you need to unwrap it to get rid of the `Optional(...)` wrapping.

You can do this e.g. using the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

```
print(responseString ?? "") // Prints "" if responseString == nil
self.lbl1.text = String(responseString ?? "")
```

or [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

```
if let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    print(responseString)
    self.lbl1.text = String(responseString)
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do if responseString is nil? If you want some other value as a placeholder then you could do that with either of dfri's options in his excellent answer. (like `self.lbl1.text = String(responseString ?? "no value"`)

Comment: @dfri I tried twelve code. print works but seems empty label .

Comment: @ÖmerBüyükçelik That is curious (unless `responseString` is `nil`, in which case it is expected). Are you sure you've tried either **1:** `self.lbl1.text = String(responseString ?? "")` or **2:** `self.lbl1.text = String(responseString)` _within_ the `if let` clause. Also note that your `UILabel` might be truncating the text if its width is limited w.r.t. the text you want it to display.

Comment: @ÖmerBüyükçelik: can you show us how the original string is converted to `NSData`?

Comment: @ÖmerBüyükçelik I'm sorry, I can't reproduce your issue with this limited information. Also, please post your code as code rather than screen shots (edit your question). Also, since your problem persists, please show us (in code blocks, not screenshots of code) a more complete example of where you run into this issue (e.g. details such as appzYourLife describes); so far, you've only shown us a small snippet out of an otherwise unknown code, making it difficult for us to help you out in detail. See [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ÖmerBüyükçelik But you actually see the `"Out = something..."` printed to your console?

Comment: @ÖmerBüyükçelik Possibly related to you setting that label within a task (asynch behaviour?).

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
print(responseString!)
```

Try this for your label:

```
self.lbl1.text = responseString!
```

This should remove the optional...

Comment: It's not prudent to use `!` when dealing with network response. It's safer to use optional binding or the like.